# Geoserver stopped working in centOS server

Tags: centos, geoserver

The Geoserver was working fine. I restarted Tomcat on CentOS. Then after that, Geoserver stopped working.
I am getting following error:
[image]

Tomcat version: 7.0.99
Geoserver version: 2.18.2

Update:
[image]

Comment: You need to turn up the logging level to developer in the global settings page, and then make the request again. Then [edit] your question with the **relevant** part of the log file.

Comment: where is global setting page?

Comment: in your case just the log file showing why geoserver didn't start should be fine

Comment: i have added catalina.out log. if anything else is needed please let me know

Comment: a picture of your error is no good to me or a screen reader